# KiCAD - Arduino shield - matching Arduino pins and schematic

Tags: arduino, pcb, pcb-design, kicad

I am trying to make an Arduino Mega shield using the KiCAD template.

The only pins connected to the Arduino are pins 3,4,5,6,22.

Here is a picture:

[image]

I am drawing a schematic, and I am trying to connect the pins to the appropriate pins.

The problem is I don't know where to hook the pins, to correspond to the analogous Arduino pins.

For example, I want to connect my circuit to the Arduino pin 3.
But if you see the template, there are many pins 3, and one of them is hooked to the reset as well.

Here is the picture of the template, with the Arduino pins:

[image]

Where should the schematic connect to, if I want to hook up Arduino pins 3,4,5,6,22 like the Arduino picture I attached earlier?

Comment: You're confused by the pin numbering of the pin sockets. As with any electronic part, the pins are numbered, but those numbers (red) are completely irrelevant for you. The pin you want is pin 5 of the socket P6.

Comment: @SimSon Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few minutes comparing some of the named signals will show that your two pictures pretty literally correspond; the only difference is that the two sides of the schematic version have been moved closer together to give more room outboard of them for names.

Simply hold your Arduino MEGA up to your monitor and you'll see the correspondence.

Then double check the actual PCB result against the labels on your physical board to make sure things ended up in the right places.

Comment: Nice observation! Thank you!